# Is in true that $R\cong R[0]\cong R[X]/(X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ a commutative ring. Is it true that $$R\cong R[0]\cong R[X]/(X)\ \ ?$$

For $R$ a field I know is correct, but for a ring, I have doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Yes ! And you also have $$R\cong R[\alpha ]\cong R[X]/(X-\alpha )$$
for all $\alpha \in R$.
Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\Phi: R[X]&\longrightarrow R[\alpha ]\\
p(X)&\longmapsto p(\alpha )
\end{align*}
is obviously surjective and it's kernel is $$\ker \varphi=(X-\alpha ).$$